# Jupyter Kernel Dies when Attempting Plot with large set of data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib

I have a numpy array `res`. `res[0]` contains x values and `res[1]` contains y values. There is in total 1000000 points.
I am trying to plot it using matplotlib; however, after running the plot, it tells me that the kernel died. I am using a jupyter notebook.

Is there  any way to avoid this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write the values to two different arrays (or lists) before plotting them. For instance this runs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define random number generation

def rng(seed,min,max,size):                                                     

    return np.random.default_rng(seed).uniform(low=min,high=max,size=size)

N = int(1e6)

res1 = rng(0,0,1,N)
res2 = rng(1,0,1,N)

plt.scatter(res1,res2,c=res1)
plt.show()
```

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnLiT.jpg)

But this fails:

```
def rng(seed,min,max,size):                                                     
    return np.random.default_rng(seed).uniform(low=min,high=max,size=size)

N = int(1e6)

res = rng(0,0,1,(N,N))

plt.scatter(res[0],res[1])
plt.show()
```

[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4YB5.jpg)

I don't know why. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but I hope this provides a quick work-around for some!